# Not able to type in Input field in React.js. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I can not able to type in Input field. Why?

```
class Profile extends Component {
  static contextType = FirebaseContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user:{}
    }

    this.updateProfile = this.updateProfile.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
        console.log("Profile")

        this.context.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

          if(user)
          {
            this.setState({user})
          } else
          {
            this.setState({user: null})
          }

        })
  }

  updateProfile(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var userData = this.context.auth.currentUser;

    userData.updateProfile({
      displayName: this.state.user.displayName
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Profile Updated");
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error Profile Updated");
    });

    userData.updateEmail(this.state.user.email).then(function() {
      console.log("Email Updated");
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error Email Updated");

    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <form onSubmit={this.updateProfile}>
      <input onChange={event => this.setState({displayName: event.currentTarget.value})} type="text" value={this.state.user.displayName} placeholder="Name" />
      <input onChange={event => this.setState({email: event.currentTarget.value})} type="email" value={this.state.user.email} placeholder="E mail Id" />
      </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you are updating state is wrong here how to do it properly :

```
   class Profile extends Component {
  static contextType = FirebaseContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: {}
    };

    this.updateProfile = this.updateProfile.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Profile");

    this.context.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
      }
    });
  }

  updateProfile(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var userData = this.context.auth.currentUser;

    userData
      .updateProfile({
        displayName: this.state.user.displayName
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Profile Updated");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error Profile Updated");
      });

    userData
      .updateEmail(this.state.user.email)
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Email Updated");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error Email Updated");
      });
  }
handleChange = e => {
const target = e.target
this.setState(current => ({
  user: { ...current.user, [target.name]: target.value }
}));
};


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.updateProfile}>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.user.displayName}
            placeholder="Name"
            name="displayName"
          />
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="email"
            value={this.state.user.email}
            placeholder="E mail Id"
            name="email"
          />
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-lehmann-o41hs?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Its giving me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` in handleChange function

Comment: oh sorry this is happening because the event is gone when accessing it from setState so to solve this you need to store the event in variable. check edited answer.

Comment: Now I can type and `displayName` is updating, but `email` is not updating. Can you tell me why? I know this should be another question. but it will be very helpful if you can figure it out whats wrong.

Comment: I meant, I can type displayName and email as well, so this question has been answered. but I am updating email and displayName in Firebase Auth. displayName is updating but email is not updating in Firebase Auth.

Comment: Its showing error `auth.esm.js:204 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/setAccountInfo?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX 400`

Comment: well you need to debug `userData.updateEmail(this.state.user.email)` how it's doing the work

Answer (score 1):

You are using different values:

```js
<input onChange={event => this.setState({displayName: event.currentTarget.value})} type="text" value={this.state.user.displayName} placeholder="Name" />
```

Your `setState` call is changing `state.displayName`, but you are reading the value from `state.user.displayName`.

Try changing your `setState` call to:

```js
this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, displayName: event.currentTarget.value } })
```

And make similar changes to your other inputs.

Comment: I did this `onChange={event => this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, displayName: event.currentTarget.value })}` but showing error `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: I missed a closing curly bracket in my answer. Try it again. It should be: `onChange={event => this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, displayName: event.currentTarget.value } })}`.

Comment: Thanks, this is also working. Now I can type and displayName is updating, but email is not updating. Can you tell me why? I know this should be another question. but it will be very helpful if you can figure it out whats wrong.

Comment: You need to make a similar change to the email input as well, such as: `onChange={event => this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, email: event.currentTarget.value } })}`. I would recommend trying to understand why the previous change made the code work though. IMHO, copy and pasting without understanding is going to make it harder for you to resolve issues in the future.

Comment: I meant, I can type displayName and email as well, so this question has been answered. but I am updating email and displayName in Firebase Auth. displayName is updating but email is not updating in Firebase Auth.

Comment: It's really hard to say anything without seeing the code. I think you'd have better luck if you asked a new question for that.